# Swift: looping into array of dictionaries (Error: Any is not convertible to NSDictionary)

Tags: swift, nsdictionary

I'm trying to run for loop in an Array of dictionaries. But I'm getting this error:

```
 Any is not convertible to NSDictionary
```

Here is my implementation:

```
let content:NSArray = json .object(forKey: "books") as! NSArray

for contentDic:NSDictionary in content {

        print(contentDic)

    }
```

[image]
How can I cast contentDic to Dictionary or NSDictionary without having this error?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can guarantee that your `content` is an array of `NSDictionary`, you can:

```
    for contentDic:NSDictionary in content as! [NSDictionary] {
        print(contentDic)

    }
```

Comment: This is a bad answer. Do no use `NSDictionary` in Swift. Use a Swift dictionary. The other answer is much better.

Comment: @rmaddy I agree it should be native Swift Dictionary, but the original question uses `NSDictionary`.

Comment: That's because the OP doesn't know what they are doing. A good answer should fix all of the issues and help show the proper solution.

Comment: Swift dictionary is preferable but that does not make using `NSDictionary` unacceptable. The original post is not about `NSDictionary` vs `Dictionary`.  I could have added few words to recommend `Dictionary` to make the answer more 'complete` but not adding that does not make it a bad answer, IMO.

Comment: Using `NSDictionary` is just going to lead to more problems because there is no type information about the contents of the dictionary. And essentially, the original question actually is about `NSDictionary` vs `Dictionary` because using `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` is what is causing the problem with `Any`. If the proper types were used instead of `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` (like the other answer), then there wouldn't have been an issue to start with. My whole point is that to someone that doesn't understand the issues, the other answer is a much better solution. It's a better practice.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the native Swift way:

```
if let content = json .object(forKey: "books") as? [[String:Any]]
    for contentDic in content {
            print(contentDic)
    }
}
```

Neither annotate types the compiler can infer nor use `NSDictionary / NSArray` in Swift. The Foundation collection types defeat the strong type system.