# Swift: accessing object variable (error: Any is not convert to)

Tags: swift

I'm array objects and I'm trying to run for loop to access one of the variables inside of the object but I'm getting this error error:

```
Any is not convert to
```

Here is my code:

```
for element:Books in jsonContent {
    print(element.title)
}
```

[image]
Any of you knows why I'm getting this error? or how can I fixed ?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: You asked the same question an hour ago

Comment: You should already have an idea how to deal with this from your previous post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528883/swift-looping-into-array-of-dictionaries-error-any-is-not-convertible-to-nsdi/43529018#43529018

Comment: You are getting this because jsonContent is not an array of Books, it is Any. I assume jsonContent is actually a dictionary, so you would need to create Books from jsonContent first.

Answer (score -2):

I figure it out:

```
for element: Books in jsonContent as! [Books] {

    print(element.title)
}
```

Comment: You should avoid force unwrapping optionals. Use `if let books = jsonContent as? [Books] { for book in books { ... } }` instead.